# Is there any way to extract chunks in pandas dataframe based on flag condition occuring multiple times

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as given below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"flag":[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
                  "Val":[1, 5, 7, 5, 4, 7, 8, 11, 13, 44, 7 , 8, 10, 14, 12]})
```

Output:

[image]

Output:

I am looking for a way to extract chunks of dataframe based on flag = 1 condition occurring multiple times

```
Chunk 1
Val flag
7    1
5    1
4    1
7    1

Chunk 2
Val flag
44   1
7    1
8    1
10   1
```

and so on
Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `Series` by compare by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) for not equal with [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and cumulative sum by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) for helper groups, then count them for 2 or more rows by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) filtered by [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html), filter only `1` values and chin both condition by `&`  for bitwise `AND` and pass to [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), last loop by groups:

```
g = df['flag'].ne(df['flag'].shift()).cumsum()

m1 = g.map(g.value_counts()).gt(1)
m2 = df['flag'].eq(1)

for k, gr in df[m1 & m2].groupby(g):
    print (gr)

   flag  Val
2     1    7
3     1    5
4     1    4
5     1    7
    flag  Val
9      1   44
10     1    7
11     1    8
12     1   10
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt support. You saved my day.